# How to store a password in a database for impersonation

Tags: .net, winforms, security, encryption, cryptography

On a Windows OS, I need a WinForms application to be able to access files (read/write/delete/modify) to a folder that the logged in user does not have access to.  Another way to say this is that the user should only be able to access the files when using the application.

In order to accomplish this, we are going to allow the application to be configured in a way that it will impersonate a user that does have access to the folder when it is executing code that needs access to the folder.  At all other times, the application will be executing as the logged in user.

The configuration settings for the application will be in a database.  Let's assume the logged in user has enough access to get the configuration settings from the database, therefore the application can load the configuration settings that include the username and password that are needed for the impersonation.

The application will be ran on multiple PCs.

What method should be used to store the password, retrieve it, and then be able to authenticate with it to do the impersonation?  Hashing, encryption, some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Since you will require the (super) username and password later (for impersonation), I recommend that you should use symmetric encryption.

Having said that,if you are deploying in an enterprise environment with Active Directory(AD), I strongly recommend that you go that route. Ie use AD to authenticate the current user and possibly configuring the application to run in the (super) user context.

Good luck